# Replace support v4 fragment with the older fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I need to replace `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` with `android.app.Fragment`. I am forced to use `android.app.Fragment`. How do I change my Fragment to inherit from `android.app.Fragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: how to launch a android.app.Fragment from android.support.v4.app.Fragment?

Comment: You can't. More or less. What is the reason you have to use the regular fragment? Maybe there is a way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `import` statement to be `android.app.Fragment` instead of the one you are importing now every where you're using it (I'd start in your `Fragment` class). There will be a few other things you might need to change, like using `FragmentManager` instead of `SupportFragmentManager` to manage your Fragments, etc. You can fix or google how to fix the errors that arise when you change your `Fragment` descendant to extend the regular `Fragment`, not the support one.

EDIT: it's usually better to use support fragments. It would be worth looking into finding an alternative resolution to the problem that's forcing you to switch.